# Skip automatic "Unsubscribe Me" feature for just one e-mail transaction

Tags: mailgun

I have a mailgun account and have been using it to send e-mails.
I've enabled the automatic "Unsubscribe Me" feature that makes it so that all e-mails sent from my account would have the "Unsubscribe" link.

However, I have an e-mail that I would like to get sent only once and would like to disable the unsubscribe me feature for this one particular e-mail.

How do I turn off the unsubscribe me feature for a specific e-mail send out only and not having to result to turning the feature off completely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is to take advantage of the modularity of Mailgun when it comes to adding domains.

Given your example, if you own say, `domain.com` you can create a subdomain `news.domain.com` or any similar subdomain name.

Disable the footer for that subdomain here:

https://mailgun.com/cp/unsubscribes?domain=**news.domain.com**

Once that's done send an email using that subdomain rather than your full-domain.

Advantages are that you keep control of your footer without any complicated code related steps and the fact that emails are still coming from your domain thus all the deliverability metrics linked to your domain and IP remain the same.

For example from the commandline

```
 curl -s --user 'api:key-apikeyapikey' \
    https://api.mailgun.net/v2/NEWS.domain.com/messages \
    -F from='me@myself.com' \
    -F to=some@customer.com \
    -F subject='Hello' \
    -F text='Testing some Mailgun awesomness!'
```

Answer (score 8):

The only way I can see is to enable the "unsubscribe me" and delete the footer code in the control panel. On your emails you want to use the Unsubscribe feature, include the following in your message.

```
%unsubscribe_url%
(link to unsubscribe recipient from all messages sent by given domain)

%tag_unsubscribe_url%
(link to unsubscribe from all tags provided in the message)

%mailing_list_unsubscribe_url%
(link to unsubscribe from future messages sent to a mailing list)
```

I know that isn't the most simple method, but would solve your issue.